# How to generate a WSDL file?

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl

i have created a webservice [.asmx] file. This web service will actually get a string as Input and insert the values to database.

Now this webservice will be called by another application, so they are asking wsdl file from me to access consume this webservice.

I know that, wsdl can be created via cmd to generate a .cs or .vb or .dll files 
And there is also a xml generated when i user ?wsdl along with my URL

But i am confused which one to provide ??!!!

Answer (score 3):

The ?wsdl on your URL is what you should provide however that means that it exists as an XML file somewhere in your project. I'm not a .net developer (java) but I do know that if ?wsdl gives it to you on the end of your url then it exists somewhere, you can just use the browser save as to save the file as a wsdl for your consumers for the time being.

Comment: If i provide the XML generated using ?wsdl, how do they use it to actually consume the webservice ?

Comment: The consumer has to import it and use a parser to generate their object set to use it (in java that's axis, jax-ws etc...) I bet a .net user will know how to use studio to get it done for .net. I imagine whoever is asking you for the wsdl will know what they want to generate it with.

Answer (score 3):

For a .asmx service running in IIS & ASP.NET, wsdl is automatically generated by using ?wsdl along with the service url. If the consumers have access to the deployed web service, then ?wsdl is the best way to provide them with service wsdl.

Otherwise, you can use WSDL.exe to generate wsdl and then pass it across.

(Regarding, your question to Thomas, for consuming a web serivce from wsdl, you need to generate client/stubs from wsdl and then using this client, you can directly make calls to the web service.

If the consumers are .NET application, then just add the service url as a web reference in the project, this should generate client/stubs from you. 
For Java, you can use some tools like wsdltojava to generate the client.)

Answer (score 3):

- Goto IIS
- Goto Content Veiw
- Browse the .asmx file
- In Browser at the end of the url add "?wsdl" and hit Enter
- This should now give you the wsdl of it.